# How could Airavata already exist before his creation in the Samudra manthan?

Tags: indra, samudra-manthan, durvasa

For me, the Samudra manthan is one of the most fascinating tales in world religion. I'm confused about an incident from that story. When Indra's vahana, Airavata, destroyed Durvasa's flower garland, the sage's curse necessitated the Samudra manthan to regain immortality for the gods. Yet one of the many creations that came out of the Samudra manthan was Airavata. How is this possible if he already existed?  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism community. Would you be able to quote from references about the two incidents you're talking about? Eg, you could share the Sanskrit verse and it's meaning, and source of text. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was the Samudra Manthan performed?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/467/why-was-the-samudra-manthan-performed) . One of the answers discuss this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40728/3881

Comment: Most of things used to exist before Samudra manthan but they entered into sea (due to Indra's misbehavior / Durvasa's curse) and re emerged again during Samudra manthan....Lakshmi ji also emerged from Samudra manthan but that doesn't mean she was not there earlier to that..