# On what did Indra ride upon before the Samudra manthan?

Tags: indra, samudra-manthan

[Why was the Samudra Manthan performed?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/467/why-was-the-samudra-manthan-performed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

According to an answer from this link and also to several references in Mahabharata, Ucchaishravas and Airavata, two mounts of Indra emerged during the churn of Samudra manthan.

What was Indra's mount before Samudra Manthan? What did he ride upon before the samudra manthan?

Comment: Airavata was already present with Lord Indra. When Rishi Durvasa cursed it disappeared and it was again recovered during Samudra Manthan.